# How to stop page jumping checkbox check which is inside the datalist itemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I have a fieldset inside that one panel on inside the panel I have a datalist, inside the itemtemplate I placed checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Chkbox" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="true" />

foreach (DataListItem dl in dlst.Items)
{
  if ((((CheckBox)dl.FindControl("Chkbox")).Checked))
  {
    Button1.Enabled = true;
  }
 }
```

when i am selecting any checkbox, page is jumping(only fieldset part is jumping) but when browserscroll position in botton of the page and ticking on checkbox then browser page is jumping, page is already inside the updatepanel, i am using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack set to True and [this approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx), but nothing is working, how to stop page jumping?

Comment: Are you sure that you're in an asynchronous postback? Check `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostback` in debugger. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have removed the autopost back from the checkbox and added a jquery on client side

[disable/enable outside asp button control on datalist checkbox checked javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476803/disable-enable-outside-asp-button-control-on-datalist-checkbox-checked-javascrip)